# Hazelcast fails to load 120 million enties into map

Tags: java, hazelcast

Actually, it's two 120M-entry maps, but I don't think that matters:

I have 2 Hazelcast instances running in a cluster with backups set to 0. There are two maps: `<Long, Long>` and `<Long, SomeClass>`. Entries are read from the file, parsed and loaded into maps. Each of two machines in the cluster has 32GB of RAM and JVM is launched wit `-XmX29G`. Last pre-fail message is

```
    INFO: [192.168.4.101]:5701 [dev] memory.used=11.9G, 
    memory.free=4.2G, memory.total=16.1G, memory.max=25.8G, 
    memory.used/total=73.96%, memory.used/max=46.12%,
    load.process=90.00%, load.system=90.00%, 
    load.systemAverage=176.00%, 
    thread.count=45, thread.peakCount=52, event.q.size=0, 
    executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, 
    executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, 
    executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, 
    executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, 
    executor.q.response.size=0, operations.remote.size=8, 
    operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=2, 
    clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=1,
    connection.count=1
```

As you see, there's enough of memory to keep some more entries, so that's not the reason to fail, I hope.

Segfault messages differ from time to time:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f708336f705, pid=24471, tid=140121186719488
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5b3705]  instanceKlass::oop_follow_contents(ParCompactionManager*, oopDesc*)+0x2c5
```

An the other day it was almost identical but with the except of the cause: problematic frame was not in `libjvm.so`, but in `collectLocalMapStats()` call within Hazelcast itself.

This happens while using both OpenJDK and Oracle Java.

Please feel free to ask for any additional information, because the matter is rather important to me and I'm willing to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably running into bug [JDK-8029679](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029679). You can find a few workaround suggestions in the comments, e.g. setting the flag `-XX:-DoEscapeAnalysis` when starting the VM.

Comment: Like Jarnobjo says, it probably is a bug in the JVM and not in the Hazelcast code.

I would like to hear more about your findings when applying his suggestions. Would be good to know if it is solved (or not).

Comment: @pveentjer, @jarnbjo, unfortunately, that didn't help. I'm still encountering either `oop_follow_contents` or `com.hazelcast.map.MapService.createLocalMapStats(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hazelcast/monitor/impl/LocalMapStatsImpl;` as a problematic frames.

Comment: @pveentjer Well, I disabled JMX service I used for monitoring the state of the cluster and it seems to run smoothly up to now. But Here is another problem - I've got those 2 nodes with 32 GB of RAM, and launch each node with `-Xmx29G`, but in Management Center it looks like there is only 29 GB of ram for BOTH nodes together. Backup count is set to 0 for both maps. What should I set up to share memory (i.e. ~58 GB) between this two nodes?

Comment: Good to know about the JMX thing.

I don't know where you see 29 GB of ram. Hazelcast will not display AFAIK in the management center the total amount of memory available in the cluster (would be nice to have btw).

Comment: I made little changes to the data model and managed to join two maps into singe. Here's what I get: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12869350/snapshot7hc.png (shows max memory = 25G at Cluster Home), https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12869350/snapshot8hc.png (shows stats on freshly launched instance), https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12869350/snapshot9hc.png (running app), https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12869350/snapshot10hc.png (new SIGSEGV cause).

Comment: I was facing the same issue on the Oracle HotSpot JVM version 8u40 b26. Nothing stated here helped, but after upgrading to the latest available version 8u51 b16 I no longer experience this issue.  CentOS 7.1 64bit.